# Error when downloading document using Response.TransmitFile()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webpage that contains a link to allow the user to download a document. The code I am using works if the user is downloading a document from a physical location (i.e C:\filename) and for documents stored as part of the website (i.e ~/Documents/filename).

But it does not work when trying to download a file from a network location and the following error occurs:  '`Could not find a part of the path`'

Here is the code I have:

```
     Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.doc");
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(@"\\ad.website.com\public\shared\filename.doc"));
        Response.End();
```

I have researched this error and it seems it can be caused by permissions or IIS setup. Is this the case  or do I need to update the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should remove `Server.MapPath` from the location..
other wise it will try to just match the path to the current server.